# Do word/phrase requests need to say what word class they want?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, single-word-requests, question-requirements

Taking [this recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/244537/59258) as an example, word/phrase request questions frequently get answers for many different word classes. It has several verbs and adjectives, and 'tooth and nail' would be an adverb I guess.

The close reason for off-topic word/phrase requests is:

> Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests

The linked page says:

> Describe the intended meaning, connotation, and/or context in as much detail as you can. ... Does the question describe exactly in what context you want to use a single word?

I think that it should be required for these request questions to specify if they are after a noun, verb, adjective etc. Those that do not should be closed. I think it would be helpful for the tag wiki page to be edited to explain that part of what 'describing the context' means is to specify a word class.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why bother? Most posters don't know what word classes are anyway, and it's just another thing to confuse them. Really, there ought to be a separate SE for word/phrase requests, with an integral dictionary and thesaurus. Those questions don't generalize very well, so they amount to dealing with every idiom in English, using different terminology for each, in different contexts, one at a time forever. Fun if you enjoy it, I spose.